# Barcode scan ZXING library

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

[image: Sample barcode]

Hi, I am integrating the zxing library in my android application. I am able to scan different barcodes. However I am unable to scan the barcode image in the above URL.It is quite big actually. It is a CODE_128 barcode. If I upload the image at the developers [site](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx)  , it is able to return to me the parsed content. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong because other smaller **CODE_128** barcode get scanned easily. Can someone please tell me if you are able to scan the attached barcode. Any other tips would be helpful too. Thanks.

This is the intent action I'm using

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE",
            "ONE_D_MODE");
```

PS: Barcode scanner apps in Google Play couldnt scan it either.

Comment: Yes I did try scanning, it works and I got result saying invalid code.

Comment: @Gru Were you able to get the number beneath the barcode ?

Comment: yes, I used NeoReader for scanning.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the IntentIntegrator as explained [here](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent)?
That seems to be a more robust way of launching the zxing scanner that creating your own Intent (with extra's) by hand.